# Delete dynamic polymorphic object allocated with placement new

Tags: c++, polymorphism, placement-new

There are two classes A & B, B is derived from A. A & B has virtual destructor. I also have two placement new functions:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size, const char* file, int line)
void* operator new[](std::size_t size, const char* file, int line)
```

and two placement delete functions:

```
void operator delete (void* p, const char* file, int line)
void operator delete[](void* p, const char* file, int line)
```

The question is, if I have vector< A*> which contains either object A or object B, how do i destroy all elements in the vector properly ?

The problem is there is no delete expression for placement delete. I can't call the default delete expression because i need the file and line argument to be supplied so i am stuck with calling directly the operator delete, which i just found out that doing so won't call the object's destructor. I also can't explicitly call the destructor because the object inside the vector could be either A or B.

**EDIT** :

I tried to do `v[i]->~A();` but B's destructor is not called even though there is a B object inside the vector

I populated the vector with something like this :

```
v[0] = new(__FILE__, __LINE__) A;
A* temp = new(__FILE__, __LINE__) B;
v[1] = temp;
```

Thank you

Comment: When you manually call the destructor on a base class pointer with a virtual destructor, I'm pretty sure that gets dynamically dispatched correctly.

Comment: A vector cannot contain either A or B. Vectors contain elements on one type only.

Comment: @KerrekSB seems stackoverflow doesnot display correctly vector<A*>. I wrote vector<A*>, but it displayed vector instead. dunno why

Comment: Use your editing powers, Luke. There's documentation on Stack Overflow's markdown syntax in the help center, and the live preview lets you verify *before submitting the question* whether it looks as intended...

Comment: Please show code on how you are populating the vector.

Comment: @NirFriedman tried it just now, it will just call the A's destructor. I call it like this : v[i]->~A(); (v is vector<A*>)

Comment: @KerrekSB i've added code on how i populate the vector

Comment: @bysreg I think you are doing something strange then. Here's an example where you can clearly see that B's destructor is called (in addition to A's destructor, remember that both get called since B inherits from A). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c8f29fd97fef27f

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question can be simplified. It reduces to solving the following problem: Given

```
A * p = new ("foo", 1) A(/* args... */);
A * q = new ("bar", 2) B(/* args... */);
```

how do you release all the adherent ownership responsibilites?

First off, you have to destroy the objects:

```
p->~A();
q->~A();
```

Thanks to the virtual destructors, that's no problem.

Now you have to release the storage. How you do that depends on what exactly your placement-new allocation function does! For example, if you have:

```
void * operator new(std::size_t n, const char *, int)
{
    return std::malloc(n);
}
```

Then you have to free memory by using `std::free(p); std::free(q);`. If your implementation instead used `return ::operator new(n)`, then you would free with `::operator delete(p)` etc. And if you're returning a pointer to static memory, then you don't have to free anything.

Since you're the one calling the placement-new allocation function, it's for you to know how to clean up!

Comment: I can't call p->~A() and q->~B() because i lost the information what p & q type's are (and the vector is dynamically expanding). I suppose i can keep their type using extra storage. But is there a way to do it without keeping track of the type ?

Comment: @bysreg: Sorry, that was meant to say `q->~A()`!